# dmidecode Result: is this a PCI Express x16 3.0 slot?

Tags: pci-express

I've run `dmidecode` on Ubuntu to see my PCI slots and the result is below:

```
Handle 0x0046, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: X16PCIEXP
    Type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 255
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:ff:00.0
```

I am planning to use a GTX 1050 Ti and it needs PCI Express x16 3.0 interface. So, does the line `Type: x16 PCI Express 3 x16` means I have that interface? Because the PC's manual does not explicitly state it is 3.0, it just says x16.

Comment: "and it needs PCI Express x16 3.0 interface. ". No it does not. It will work perfectly fine in an x1 slot, or an x4 slot, or x8, or x16. And it will work fine with PCI-e v2. And it should even work fine with PCI-e v1.

Comment: What probably is intended 'to get absolutely best max performance from this cards use, use x16 and at least PCI-e v3. But it will run perfectly fine with other combinations.

Comment: @Hennes yes, you are right. Indeed, I meant using it to its fullest potential.
What I really want to know is that output of dmidecode means 3.0 or not actually.